# In jQuery Mobile, why doesn't this popup close?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am calling close as per http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/index.html, but nothing is happening (obviously I expect it not to show at all in this situation):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>popup</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset= ISO-8859-5">
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#popupBasic").popup();
        $("#popupBasic").popup("open");
        $("#popupBasic").popup("close");
    });
    </script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
        <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

put your script into the body and it works, I added additionally a header

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>popup</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset= ISO-8859-5">
</head>
<body>

  <div data-role="page" id="myPage">
    <div data-role="content">
      <h1>Popup</h1>
      <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
        <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
          $("#popupBasic").popup();
          $("#popupBasic").popup("open");
          $("#popupBasic").popup("close");
        }, 100);
      });
    </script>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: use `$(document).bind('pageinit')` instead of `$(document).ready()` as described [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html) and now added a short delay of 100ms. Works now in Firefox Nightly and Chrome...

Comment: This produces strange behaviour in Chrome - when the popup is closed it also goes to a blank page. In Safari it does not seem to work at all.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, still observing strange behaviour in Chrome with this. When the popup is closed it goes to a blank page.

Comment: With which operation system do you use Chrome? Works fine with Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. I had a navigate event with alert in my code, and alert was indicating that navigate event is called after popup in chrome, and because jQM is not writing page with popup into history you are going back to first welcome page of chrome.

I have not resolved this problem, so I have used this plugin:

Magnific Popup v0.9.4 by Dmitry Semenov

Popup was opened directly via API in my jQM "pageshow" event.
Here is the page: http://kancelaria.danekilian2.pl/

Comment: You could improve this answer by specifying which plugin you used to solve the problem.