# jQuery mobile popup is not closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

sorry for not supplying a fiddle, I can't get it set up there.

However, I use the following code to programatically open and close a popup. Only that it doesn't close and stays open. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#initialpopup").popup("open");

        setTimeout(function()
        {
            $("#initialpopup").popup("close");
        }, 500);    

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="c">

        <div data-role="popup" id="initialpopup" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a">Foobar</div>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to close this automatically after 5 seconds?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154278/in-jquery-mobile-why-doesnt-this-popup-close

Comment: After 500 milliseconds. The timeout symbolizes the complete callback handler of an ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
$('#initialpopup').popup('open', {transition: 'pop'});
window.setTimeout('$("#initialpopup").popup("close");', 500);
```

Comment: Why would this make a difference? Is there a significance to using an eval'd string rather than a lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the same case as the one reported here, but I had the same problem and fixed it with this extra CSS:

```
        .ui-popup-container [data-role=popup] {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        .ui-popup-container.ui-popup-active [data-role=popup] {
            visibility: inherit;
        }
        .ui-popup-screen.out {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
```

I believe there was a screw-up in the library at some point in time, or we might be missing something...

I feel this is related to the animations somehow, but I haven't found a way to properly fix it.